# Gets redirected to Home route when no routes are defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I used Angular.js routing mechanism where I want to set my home route as default, so that when I open application will use that default routing.

Example When I open application as follows url is www.abc.com

Code :

```
var portalModule = angular.module("portalModule", ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    //Path - it should be same as href link
    $routeProvider.when('/Home', { templateUrl: '/PortalTemplate/Home.html', controller: 'homeController' });

    //List routing
    $routeProvider.when('/ProductList', { templateUrl: '/PortalTemplate/ProductList.html', controller: 'productController' });
    $routeProvider.when('/ShopList', { templateUrl: '/PortalTemplate/ShopList.html', controller: 'shopController' });
    $routeProvider.when('/ServiceList', { templateUrl: '/PortalTemplate/ServiceList.html', controller: 'serviceController' });

    //Detail Routing
    $routeProvider.when('/ProductDetail', { templateUrl: '/PortalTemplate/ProductDetail.html', controller: 'productDetailController' });
    $routeProvider.when('/ShopDetail', { templateUrl: '/PortalTemplate/ShopDetail.html', controller: 'shopDetailController' });
    $routeProvider.when('/ServiceDetail', { templateUrl: '/PortalTemplate/ServiceDetail.html', controller: 'serviceDetailController' });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

So I want /Home route will open as whenever I open my application as www.abc.com/Home by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.otherwise(params);` which will catch anything else that doesn't match. See [roteProvider docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

```
$routeProvider.when(...)
$routeProvider.when(...)
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Home' });
```